# WooCommerce 4: Gallery size is too large in mobile

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

> *This question is no longer valid, as the code has been changed and the problem is fixed.*

I'm working on my custom theme, and try to fit Bootstrap grid layout into the product page. The product page looks fine in the desktop version, but the product image looks very big in mobile version. Please see this link:

https://www.thekwinana.com/product/rose-quartz-generator/

Can you please advise? Thanks!

Here are the codes I use (only show the part that is related):

**mytheme/woocommerce/content-single-product.php**

```
<div class="col-11 col-md-5 product">
    <?php
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary' );
    ?>
</div>
```

**mytheme/woocommerce/single-product/product-image.php**

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

// Note: `wc_get_gallery_image_html` was added in WC 3.3.2 and did not exist prior. This check protects against theme overrides being used on older versions of WC.
if ( ! function_exists( 'wc_get_gallery_image_html' ) ) {
    return;
}

global $product;

$columns           = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails_columns', 4 );
$post_thumbnail_id = $product->get_image_id();
$wrapper_classes   = apply_filters(
    'woocommerce_single_product_image_gallery_classes',
    array(
        'woocommerce-product-gallery',
        'woocommerce-product-gallery--' . ( $product->get_image_id() ? 'with-images' : 'without-images' ),
        'woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-' . absint( $columns ),
        'images',
    )
);
?>
<!-- product-image.php -->
<div class="<?php echo esc_attr( implode( ' ', array_map( 'sanitize_html_class', $wrapper_classes ) ) ); ?>" data-columns="<?php echo esc_attr( $columns ); ?>" style="opacity: 0; transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;">
    <figure class="woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper">
        <?php
        if ( $product->get_image_id() ) {
            //$html = wc_get_gallery_image_html( $post_thumbnail_id, false );
            
            $gallery_thumbnail = wc_get_image_size( 'gallery_thumbnail' );
            $thumbnail_size    = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail_size', array( $gallery_thumbnail['width'], $gallery_thumbnail['height'] ) );
            $thumbnail_src     = wp_get_attachment_image_src(  $post_thumbnail_id, $thumbnail_size );
            $full_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, 'full');
            $html  = '<div data-thumb="' . esc_url( $thumbnail_src[0] ) . '" data-thumb-alt="" class="woocommerce-product-gallery__image">';
            $html .= '<a href="' . esc_url( $full_src[0] ) . '"><img src="' . $full_src[0] . '" alt="" class="img-fluid" /></a>';
            $html .= '</div>';
        } else {
            $html  = '<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery__image--placeholder">';
            $html .= sprintf( '<img src="%s" alt="%s" class="wp-post-image" />', esc_url( wc_placeholder_img_src( 'woocommerce_single' ) ), esc_html__( 'Awaiting product image', 'woocommerce' ) );
            $html .= '</div>';
        }

        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', $html, $post_thumbnail_id ); // phpcs:disable WordPress.XSS.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped

        do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' );
        ?>
    </figure>
</div>
```

As you can see from the `product-image.php`, the original `wc_get_gallery_image_html()` function is bypassed with codes nearly the same as the ones in the WooCommerce plugin. The only difference is to add custom CSS classes into the HTML structure, in order to fix the sizing problems in the desktop version.

For the WooCommerce custom CSS in my `style.css` in the theme:

```
.single-product div.product {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.single-product div.product::before, .single-product div.product::after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
}
.single-product div.product::after {
    clear: both; 
}
.single-product div.product .images,
.single-product div.product .summary,
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery {
    margin-bottom: 2.617924em;
    margin-top: 0; 
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery {
    position: relative;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery .zoomImg {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery .woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper .flex-active-slide > a > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery .woocommerce-product-gallery__trigger {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.875em;
    right: 0.875em;
    display: block;
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    border-radius: 3px;
    z-index: 99;
    text-align: center;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery img {
    margin: 0;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery .flex-viewport {
    margin-bottom: 1.618em;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery .flex-control-thumbs {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery .flex-control-thumbs::before, .single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery .flex-control-thumbs::after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery .flex-control-thumbs::after {
    clear: both;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery .flex-control-thumbs li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 1.618em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery .flex-control-thumbs li img {
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transition: all, ease, 0.2s;
    transition: all, ease, 0.2s;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery .flex-control-thumbs li img.flex-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery .flex-control-thumbs li:hover img {
    opacity: 1;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery.woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-2 .flex-control-thumbs li {
    width: 42.8571428571%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 14.2857142857%;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery.woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-2 .flex-control-thumbs li:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery.woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-2 .flex-control-thumbs li:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery.woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-3 .flex-control-thumbs li {
    width: 23.8095238%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 14.2857142857%;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery.woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-3 .flex-control-thumbs li:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery.woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-3 .flex-control-thumbs li:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery.woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-4 .flex-control-thumbs li {
    width: 14.2857142857%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 13%;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery.woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-4 .flex-control-thumbs li img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery.woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-4 .flex-control-thumbs li:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery.woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-4 .flex-control-thumbs li:nth-child(4n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery.woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-5 .flex-control-thumbs li {
    width: 8.5714285714%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 14.2857142857%;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery.woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-5 .flex-control-thumbs li:nth-child(5n) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery.woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-5 .flex-control-thumbs li:nth-child(5n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
.single-product div.product .images .woocommerce-main-image {
    margin-bottom: 1.618em;
    display: block;
}
.single-product div.product .images .thumbnails a.zoom {
    display: block;
    width: 22.05%;
    margin-right: 3.8%;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.single-product div.product .images .thumbnails a.zoom.last {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.single-product div.product .images .thumbnails a.zoom.first {
    clear: both;
}
.single-product div.product form.cart {
    margin-bottom: 1.618em;
    padding: 1em 0;
}
.single-product div.product form.cart::before, .single-product div.product form.cart::after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
}
.single-product div.product form.cart::after {
    clear: both;
}
.single-product div.product form.cart .quantity {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.875em;
}
.single-product div.product form.cart table.woocommerce-grouped-product-list .woocommerce-grouped-product-list-item__label {
    overflow-wrap: anywhere;
    word-break: break-word;
    -ms-word-break: break-all;
}
.single-product div.product form.cart table.woocommerce-grouped-product-list .woocommerce-grouped-product-list-item__quantity {
    float: none;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.single-product div.product form.cart table.woocommerce-grouped-product-list .woocommerce-grouped-product-list-item__quantity .quantity {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.single-product div.product p.price {
    font-size: 1.41575em;
    margin: 1.41575em 0;
}
.single-product div.product table.variations {
    table-layout: fixed;
    margin: 0; 
}
.single-product div.product table.variations th,
.single-product div.product table.variations td {
    display: list-item;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.single-product div.product table.variations .value {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.single-product div.product table.variations select {
    max-width: 70%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.single-product div.product .single_variation .price {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    display: block;
}
.single-product div.product .variations_button {
    padding-top: 1em;
}
.single-product div.product .variations_button::before, .single-product div.product .variations_button::after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
}
.single-product div.product .variations_button::after {
    clear: both;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-rating {
    margin-bottom: 1.618em;
    margin-top: -0.875em;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-rating::before, .single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-rating::after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-rating::after {
    clear: both;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-rating a {
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-rating a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-rating .star-rating {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.6180469716em;
}
.single-product div.product .product_meta {
    font-size: 0.875em;
    padding-top: 1em;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.single-product div.product .product_meta .sku_wrapper,
.single-product div.product .product_meta .posted_in,
.single-product div.product .product_meta .tagged_as {
    display: block; 
}
.single-product div.product .product_meta .sku_wrapper:last-child,
.single-product div.product .product_meta .posted_in:last-child,
.single-product div.product .product_meta .tagged_as:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0; 
}
.single-product div.product .product_meta a {
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.single-product div.product .product_meta a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.single-product div.product .edit-link {
    font-size: 0.875em;
    margin-top: 1em;
}
    
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery .woocommerce-product-gallery__trigger {
    text-indent: -999px;
    overflow: hidden; 
    color: #CCC;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery .woocommerce-product-gallery__trigger::before {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    font-weight: 900;
    line-height: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    content: "\f00e";
    display: block;
    line-height: 2;
    text-indent: 0;
}
.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery .woocommerce-product-gallery__trigger img {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Raptor you can try setting a max-height on the image (container). The current layout is problematic because it is a portrait image and the width is related to the browser width. The image keeps its aspect ratio and therefore is very high. Can you also share the PHP code for that part of the layout?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Codes added.

Comment: Allright, thanks. If you just want to add (or use) classes for the image, you could try the `wp-post-image` class. If you want to add a class, you can add an attribute to an element like a div: `class="new-personal-class new-second-personal-class"`. This code adds two classes, separated with a space. So if there already exists a class, use a space to separate them. Now you can use that class to target that specific element in CSS.

Comment: I know how to add custom CSS classes to HTML, but I just want to know how to adjust the CSS in order to fix the sizing issues in mobile. thanks.

Comment: I had a look, could you please explain why some elements/containers are 7000+ px wide? Or 600%? I think that's why it's all messed up.

Comment: @ralphsmit It's not defined in the CSS. I think it's due to WooCommerce's Product Gallery feature. I'm using the default gallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to limit the height on mobile:

```
@media (max-width:480px) {
   .carousel-item img {
      max-height: 200px; 
      object-fit: contain;
   }
}
```